# How to get Hold Time and Change time from same table

Tags: sql

I am writing a query to get first changed timestamp by record ID and the time it remained in the same status.
So if the table is

| id | Status | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Hold | 2022-04-12 00:00:00 |
| B | Available | 2022-04-13 00:00:00 |
| C | Hold | 2022-04-14 00:00:00 |
| D | Hold | 2022-04-13 00:00:00 |
| A | Hold | 2022-04-12 06:00:00 |
| C | QA | 2022-04-14 08:00:00 |
| D | Available | 2022-04-13 02:00:00 |
| E | Available | 2022-04-15 00:00:00 |
| A | Available | 2022-04-16 00:00:00 |
| F | Available | 2022-04-17 00:00:00 |

Output:

| id | Hold Time | Change Time | Change Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-04-12 00:00:00 | 2022-04-16 00:00:00 | Available |
| C | 2022-04-14 00:00:00 | 2022-04-14 08:00:00 | QA |
| D | 2022-04-13 00:00:00 | 2022-04-13 02:00:00 | Available |
| F | 2022-04-16 00:00:00 | 2022-04-17 00:00:00 | Available |

Basically, I need to track when a record gets put on hold and the first instance that it comes off hold.

I have been able to get the first two columns easily, but have not been able to get the third column onwards.

Comment: Please post the SQL you are using. That will be useful in detecting a bug, or in suggesting an alternative approach.

Comment: Also, the ID appears to represent the type of job recorded. Do you also have a unique record id when a row is added? This will enable full query capabilities.

Comment: Yes, there is an sequence to denote record ID, but I need to only group by this ID(A, B, C). I will post the code I am using as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using sql server
you can try this query

```
select p.id,b.[time],p.[status] as [change value]
from (
select*
from your_table_name
where [status] not in ('Hold')) as p
join (
select id,[status],min([time]) as [time]
from your_table_name
where [status] = 'Hold'
group by id,[status]) as b
on p.id = b.id
```

but this query can not get your value with id F cause by your example data, id f dont have status = hold

[image: result screenshot]

hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  `id` VARCHAR(1),
  `Status` VARCHAR(9),
  `Time` DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO t
  (`id`, `Status`, `Time`)
VALUES
  ('A', 'Hold', '2022-04-12 00:00:00'),
  ('B', 'Available', '2022-04-13 00:00:00'),
  ('C', 'Hold', '2022-04-14 00:00:00'),
  ('D', 'Hold', '2022-04-13 00:00:00'),
  ('A', 'Hold', '2022-04-12 06:00:00'),
  ('C', 'QA', '2022-04-14 08:00:00'),
  ('D', 'Available', '2022-04-13 02:00:00'),
  ('E', 'Available', '2022-04-15 00:00:00'),
  ('A', 'Available', '2022-04-16 00:00:00'),
  ('F', 'Available', '2022-04-17 00:00:00');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT id
    , MAX(Hold_Time) AS Hold_Time
    , MIN(CASE WHEN Time > Hold_Time THEN Time END) AS Change_Time
    , Status
FROM t
JOIN (
  SELECT id
       , MIN(CASE WHEN Status = 'Hold' THEN Time END) AS Hold_Time
  FROM t
  GROUP BY id
) t2 USING(id)
WHERE Status <> 'Hold' and Hold_Time IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id, Status;
```

| id | Status | Hold_Time | Change_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Available | 2022-04-12 00:00:00 | 2022-04-16 00:00:00 |
| C | QA | 2022-04-14 00:00:00 | 2022-04-14 08:00:00 |
| D | Available | 2022-04-13 00:00:00 | 2022-04-13 02:00:00 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w8xtLE64v3fiyenzVhGWjC/0)